# How to change the Name of Logical volume in Volume group

Tags: rhel, mount, rename, lvm

I created an LVM and inside that i created Volume Group and within it created Logical Volume and given the mount point /u001/app/pracle I named it wrong instead of **ORACLE** i it should have been typed **PRACLE**.

Now installation of RHEL 5.6 is complete and i noticed it now. How can i change this from **/u001/app/pracle** to **/u001/app/oracle**

[image: DF]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you seem not interested in useful volume group and volume names (currently your vg is named `VolGroup00` and your lv `LogVol01`), I'll leave these untouched.

So the only need is to change the mount point, so you edit `/etc/fstab` and change the respective line from `pracle` to `oracle`. That is for the next reboot.

Then do

```
mkdir /u001/app/oracle   # necessary before changes can take effect!
umount /u001/app/pracle  # unmount the old one
mount /u001/app/oracle   # mount it on the new place
rmdir /u001/app/pracle   # and dispose of the garbage.
```

for cleaning up and for having the changes immediately.

---

On the long run, it might be useful to at least have useful volume names: that's what `lvrename` is for. You would do that with

```
lvrename VolGroup00/LogVol01 oracle
```

after which an edit of the fstab is necessary again, as the device location changes from `/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01` to `/dev/VolGroup00/oracle` resp. from `/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01` to `/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-oracle`.

Comment: Dear I followed ur instructions but always say that please type correct volume name. This is the command i types **LVRENAME VOLGROUP00-LOGVOL01/PRACLE ORACLE** What wrong im doing here thanks

Comment: Are you really using uppercase letters? That's not good. Besides, probably you have your LV name different from your mount point name. What do `vgs` and `lvs` tell you about their names?

Comment: Ouch, I just saw your screen shot. (Why not just copy & paste text?!) So I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Actually the server access was not allowed from Network team so i had to manually take the picture.

Comment: Great help my friend

Comment: @UmairMustafa Glad I could help